# How to switch tabs using keyboard on bigsur?

Tags: macos, keyboard, big-sur

I have enabled Prefer tabs feature on macos bigsur

[image]

Now I wonder how to switch those tabs using keyboard shortcut. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a lot of applications (e.g. Finder, Safari, Terminal) it's <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Hm, works in all apps other than Jetbrains IDE. Thanks for answer and I'll direct more specific question their way ;)

Comment: @simPod It probably works for all applications using the usual macOS frameworks, and won't work for any other.